# Suspected threading issues when using JaversAuditableAuditAsync

Tags: javers

I am using Javers with Spring Hibernate JPA. The primary database is a MYSQL database with Javers connected to a seperate MongoDB server. I am not using Spring Data.

Everything works great with JaversAuditableAspect but I get the below errors when I use JaversAuditableAspectAsync.

I am using the default setup for the Async Javers.

```
@Bean
public JaversAuditableAspectAsync javersAuditableAspectAsync() {
    
    return new JaversAuditableAspectAsync(javers(), authorProvider(), new EmptyPropertiesProvider(), javersAsyncAuditExecutor());
}

@Bean
public ExecutorService javersAsyncAuditExecutor() {
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat("JaversAuditableAsync-%d")
            .build();
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, threadFactory);
}
```

I understand this is an experimental feature but performance is very important in the area I intend to use Javers. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Errors upon first change attempt:

```
2020-07-29 10:54:35:497 [asdf@asdf.com E6DD9F] ERROR 
DefaultRestExceptionHandler.defaultErrorHandler:120 - Error invoking '/service/form/save'. Exception: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException. Message: Could not commit JPA   transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the  transaction. 
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
```

Errors upon 2nd or more attempts:

```
2020-07-29 11:24:48:311 [asdf@asdf.com CD065A] ERROR DefaultRestExceptionHandler.defaultErrorHandler:120 - Error invoking '/service/form/save'. Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. Message: null. 
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
```

Comment: is an experimental feature :) you are welcome to contribute a fix

Comment: Not passive aggressive at all